# Can I deploy deploy reports created on SQL 2008 R2 server onto the 2008 R2 server but used a SQL 2005 database on a different server as data source

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a 2008 R2 Server and using it to create SSRS reports. The shared data source is actually located on a SQL 2005 server.

I tried to deploy a report to the local server (SQL 2008 R2) and got error :

> "Cannot deploy the report because the shared data source that the
>   report references does not exist on the report server"

Is it possible to deploy these reports created on the 2008 R2 Server to the same machine(2008 R2 server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  Make sure you deploy the shared data source.

Look under the 'Shared Data Sources' folder in your Solution Explorer.  Right click -> `Deploy`.